# Given a triangle $ABC$, Find a point $P$ such that $PA:PB:PC=1:2:3.$

Tags: geometry, triangles

"Given a triangle $ABC$, Find a point $P$ such that $PA:PB:PC=1:2:3.$

I found this on a Olympiad book, and I was unable  to solve it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It is enough to intersect two Apollonian circles (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circles_of_Apollonius).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the straight line $AB$, let $D$ and $E$ be two distinct points such that $\frac{AD}{DB}=\frac{1}{2}=\frac{AE}{EB}$.  On the straight line $BC$, let $F$ and $G$ be two distinct points such that $\frac{BF}{FC}=\frac{2}{3}=\frac{BG}{GC}$.  Consider the intersection points $Q$ and $R$ of the circle with diameter $DE$ with the circle with diameter $FG$.  Then, a point $P$ satisfies $AP:BP:CP=1:2:3$ iff $P\in\{Q,R\}$.